# Boletus or Xerocomellus?

Tags: mycology

I have been trying to identify a mushroom I collected in the nearby forest, and while I think I have it identified, it seems to have a couple of names and I am confused about which grouping is correct.

According to one site, the mushroom is Boletus Chrysenteron :http://www.mycokey.org/result.shtml?genSpec=Species&ID=213&showList=DropDown&random=11837

According to Wikipedia it is Xerocomellus Chrysenteron (picture on right) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xerocomellus

But the info suggests that this Xerocomellus group is relatively new and belongs to the family Bolataceae.

Are these two different mushrooms (Xerocomellus Chrysenteron and Boletus Chrysenteron)? Or is it that the mushroom is now in a new group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you will see in [the Species section of the Wikipedia *Xerocomellus* genus page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xerocomellus#Species) you linked, *Xerocomellus chrysenteron* has a [basionym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basionym) (original name) of *Boletus chrysenteron*.  The *Xerocomellus* genus was first described in 2008.  The [Wikipedia page for the *X. chrysenteron* species](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xerocomellus_chrysenteron) similarly gives three synonyms for *X. chrysenteron* in the box at the top; among them is *Boletus chrysenteron* Bull. (1789).  Thus the two names are referring to the same mushroom species.

One should note that [Wikipedia says about this species](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xerocomellus_chrysenteron#Similarities_within_taxa):

> Macroscopic observation of Xerocomellus chrysenteron is not sufficient
>   to determine this species with certainty, as many intermediate forms
>   occur between it and other taxa

It appears from this that correct identification of a mushroom as being *X. chrysenteron* is not a trivial task.